# Wireless Driver Not Working Ubuntu / OS X dual boot

Tags: macos, ubuntu, wireless-networking, macbook-pro, multi-boot

I'm using a MacBook Pro 10, dual-booting Mac OS X 10.6.8 and Ubuntu 11.04.

Ubuntu is working well for all intents and purposes, except there is no internet connectivity, due to the fact that Ubuntu is not yet compatible with the broadband 4331 wireless driver, and cannot identify it.

The only way I know of identifying the driver is by using the `indswrapper`, but that has shown to create problems with the boot-up for the OS X side. Any comments or suggestions?

Comment: Have you've tried connecting it through Ethernet? My experience in installing Ubuntu on Mac is that it auto-detects the driver it needs in its interface and asks you if you want to install a non-free driver.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at this [page](http://homepage.uibk.ac.at/~c705283/archives/2011/09/04/linux_support_for_broadcom_4331_wireless_chip_macbook_pro_81/index.html). They say that:

> The driver (for the Broadcom 4331) is announced for kernel version 3.2, but if you don't want
>   to wait for this kernel it is possible to compile and use the relevant
>   module with older kernels.

They indicate step by step how to get the driver working with previous kernels. I have found such page from comments of several users that seem to have achieved to get this wireless device (Broadcom 4331, device id 14e4:4331) working in Linux.